# Set event listener programmatically in nativescript-vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm developing my first app using NativeScript Vue and I was hoping someone could help me with an issue here: How do you set an event listener to a component programmatically? In a normal vue app you would do: `component.$on('eventName', eventHandler)`, but that is not working. I tried to get the answer searching the matter in google, but with no results. Thank you all

Comment: Do you get any errors reported back you? And if so maybe you could share them with us.

Comment: Are you trying to listen to event on Vue Component / NativeScript UI element?

Comment: I was trying to listen to an event on a Vue component using the method '$on', but apparently, that interface is not implemented in nativescript-vue plugin. There was no error thrown, just didn't work. I resolved what I needed by using the nativescript event handler instead of vue's event handler interface.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved what I needed by using the nativescript event handler instead of vue's event handler interface. https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events

I was trying to listen to a page event, so my code looks something like this:

```
const Page = require('tns-core-modules/ui/page').Page

const componentPage = vueComponent.nativeView.page
componentPage.on(Page.navigatedFromEvent, myHandlerMethod)
```

Comment: How do you access the `vueComponent.nativeView `?